# Lumen 5.3 send email

Tags: laravel, phpmailer, lumen

I tried send a email from Lumen using gmail smtp config. I am using:

- `illuminate/mail`, Version `5.3`
- `lumen`, Version  `5.3`

I can't send an email.

My router:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('mail','mailcontroller@mail');
});
```

My `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
    $this->app->singleton('mailer', function ($app) {
        $app->configure('services');
        return $app->loadComponent('mail', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'mailer');
        });
    }
}
```

My `.env` configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*******@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My mail controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class mailcontroller extends Controller {
    public function mail(){
        Mail::raw('Raw string email', function($msg) { 
            $msg->to(['****.com']); 
            $msg->from(['*****@gmail.com']); });
    }
}
```

Also i have enable following lines in `app.php`:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->withFacades();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A little late to the party, but here's how I've done it in Lumen 5.4 (and I know it might be a little clumsy and not suitable for everyone, but still):

**1)** pull in `illuminate/mail`:

`composer require illuminate/mail`

**2)** add the service provider to your `bootstrap/app.php`:

`$app->register(\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);` and uncomment `$app->withFacades();`

**It's possible/likely the following can be achieved through `.env` but I haven't tried:**

**3)** Install phanan's cascading config - https://github.com/phanan/cascading-config and follow the installation process for Lumen described there

**4)** create `config` folder in your application's root and copy-paste full Laravel's `config/mail.php`

**5)** add `$app->configure('mail');` to `bootstrap/app.php`

**6)** make sure the actual config in `mail.php` is correct

Now you should be able to send mails the same way you do in full Laravel installation.

Comment: If anyone is struggling resolving Mailer via typehinting, I had to add `$this->app->alias('mailer','Illuminate\Mail\Mailer');` after the app bootrapped (I added it in the register method of AppServiceProvider)

Comment: If someone have trouble with installing `illuminate/mail` (problem with version), do `composer show --installed | grep illuminate` and notice version. Then run `composer require illuminate/mail:~version.number`. Alfter that, i was able to follow your steps @GTCrais. Thanks mate.

Comment: Facing problem when i try to send mail.  **FatalThrowableError**   Class 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider' not found

Answer (score 1):

If php 7.1 is installed, use Mail 5.7 version

```
composer require illuminate/mail 5.7.*
```