# Lumen 5.4 with Laravel Mailable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, lumen, laravel-artisan

Naive question: is there a way to use Artisan to create a Mailable class within Lumen framework like this: `php artisan make:mail OrderShipped` (example taken from the docs).

Here is the **composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/lumen",
"description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.4.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "illuminate/mail": "5.4",
    "phanan/cascading-config": "~2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~0.9"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/",
        "database/"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

This is how **bootstrap/app.php** has been modified (added all of these):

```
$app->withFacades( true, [
  'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail' => 'Mail',
]);

$app->register(\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('mail');
$app->alias('mailer','Illuminate\Mail\Mailer');
config('mail');
```

And this is what `php artisan` gives me:

```
Laravel Framework Lumen (5.4.7) (Laravel Components 5.4.*)

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help                Displays help for a command
  list                Lists commands
  migrate             Run the database migrations
 auth
  auth:clear-resets   Flush expired password reset tokens
 cache
  cache:clear         Flush the application cache
  cache:forget        Remove an item from the cache
  cache:table         Create a migration for the cache database table
 db
  db:seed             Seed the database with records
 make
  make:migration      Create a new migration file
  make:seeder         Create a new seeder class
 migrate
  migrate:install     Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh     Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset       Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback    Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status      Show the status of each migration
 queue
  queue:failed        List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:failed-table  Create a migration for the failed queue jobs database table
  queue:flush         Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget        Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen        Listen to a given queue
  queue:restart       Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry         Retry a failed queue job
  queue:table         Create a migration for the queue jobs database table
  queue:work          Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon
 schedule
  schedule:run        Run the scheduled commands
```

I am on OS X El Capitan, Apache2, PHP 5.6.31

So again, how (if at all) can I use artisan to make:mail? If this is not achievable without full-blown Laravel, is there a template to create Mailable classes? Will they be usable?

Refs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#generating-mailables
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-and-fast-emails-with-laravel-5-3-mailables
- [Lumen 5.3 send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728207/lumen-5-3-send-email) (no make:mail?)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are some packages that allow that exactly. For example:

https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator

As **stated on their readme**, to install the Composer package:

```
composer require flipbox/lumen-generator
```

And then add on `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
$app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
```

If you then run `php artisan` on command line, you get new commands:

```
 Available commands:
  clear-compiled      Remove the compiled class file
  help                Displays help for a command
  list                Lists commands
  migrate             Run the database migrations
  optimize            Optimize the framework for better performance
  serve               Serve the application on the PHP development server
  tinker              Interact with your application
 key
  key:generate        Set the application key
 make
  make:command        Create a new Artisan command
  make:controller     Create a new controller class
  make:event          Create a new event class
  make:job            Create a new job class
  make:listener       Create a new event listener class
  make:mail           Create a new email class
  make:middleware     Create a new middleware class
  make:migration      Create a new migration file
  make:model          Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:policy         Create a new policy class
  make:provider       Create a new service provider class
  make:seeder         Create a new seeder class
  make:test           Create a new test class
```