# Forcing PHP mail to mock success on dev server

Tags: php, email, virtualbox

I'm developing a Lumen API (on a VirtualBox) which will occasionally send out emails. However, on my dev server, I don't want to send mails; rather, I'd like the server to fake sending the mail and just return true. In the past, I've done conditionals that check if I'm on the dev server, if so, skip the entire sending mail process, but this feels like the wrong way to do it.

So what I'm trying to get to is: can I somehow get the server to not try sending the email and just move on? Am I thinking about this wrong, and should I try to get mail working on my VB or is a conditional the right way to go after all? I'd love advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending emails using illumenate/mail ([Lumen 5.3 send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728207/lumen-5-3-send-email)) you can set up the mail driver to log in your .env file for your dev environment. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail.

If you are using your own functions for sending emails you should still get smtp server from .env, so you can set it to a server that will not send out any emails

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Coincidentally, I found that SO question last night but thought setting up a package to just send mails off my local server (right now, I've been sending mails via PHP's built in `mail` function) was overkill. I won't pretend I understand mail servers at all... it worked on my prod server from the start, and I was grateful.

Comment: And now that I think about it, based on your response, if this wasn't Laravel/Lumen, the solution would be to write conditionals (or a class that handles it) based on environment, as that's what the illuminate mail class is doing.