# cannot send email in Ubuntu Server using RestAPI Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, email, ubuntu, lumen

I have been Hosting My Lumen in Unbutu Linux Server, Now my problem is i cannot send any email.
before that, i can send email when still in Localhost with this way :

[Lumen 5.3 send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728207/lumen-5-3-send-email)

There is no error showing
[Webpage display Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLNDb.png)

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as domPDF;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function generatePDF()

    {
        $pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');


        $data = ['title' => 'Welcome to HDTuto.com'];

        $pdf = $pdf->loadView('myPDF', $data);
        $pdf->setPaper('Letter', 'potrait');
        return $pdf->download('hdtuto.pdf');

    }
}
```

Route

```
$router->get('email', function () use ($router) {
    $data = ['username' => "test5", 'password' => "password", 'email' => "test@email.com"];

    Mail::send('emails.signup', $data, function ($mail)
    {

                $mail->to('test@yahoo.com');


                $mail->subject('Sign Up Success');
            });
    return response('yes');
});
```

app.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}


$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->withFacades(true, [ 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail' => 'Mail',]);

$app->withEloquent();


$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);


$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('dompdf');
$app->configure('services');
$app->configure('mail');

$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

i have tried many ways to get that fix, but unfortunately there still not fixed.

I Think the problem is all of ServiceProvider not working, due to my PDF Generator doesn't work too

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site. Please include the error message you're getting, logs, or any code that might help others guide you in finding a solution to your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please check SMTP details,depends on hosting server, last month i also suffered with the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some code you have tried yourself instead of putting a link. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, can you post your code that is not working and related errors you are getting.

Comment: @syam
I have editted my post with some code and picture

Comment: @AndroidGears I have editted my post with some code and picture

Comment: hope this helps you. refer this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#mail-and-local-development